# How do I handle routing in PagesJL without specifying every file as an Endpoint?

Tags: julia

As indicated in the github README, an Endpoint is defined like this:

```
julia> Endpoint("/hello") do request::Request
           "Hello world"
       end
```

I would like to know how to define an endpoint with pages and serve all files in that directory without having to specify each one as an endpoint. What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't do what you want if you adapt next example from README? ->

```
julia> Endpoint("/do_something") do request::Request
       uri = URI(request.resource)
       param = query_params(uri)
       do_something(param["file"])
       end
Endpoint created at /do_something.

# Opening the url http://localhost:8000/do_something?file=filename now do something with "filename".
```